# JavaFX Combobox displays other entry than selected

Tags: javafx, combobox, wrapper, equals

I noticed that the value displayed in a ComboBox after selecting one from the list can be different than the selected one if the two values are equal according to their equals-method (but have a different representation according to the toString-method, thus display differently).

This can be seen from the following sample program

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Group group = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(group,100,40);

            ObservableList<EqualContent> content = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            content.add(new EqualContent("A"));
            content.add(new EqualContent("B"));

            Label selection = new Label();

            ComboBox<EqualContent> demoBox = new ComboBox<EqualContent>(content);
            demoBox.setOnAction(event -> selection.setText(" selected: "+demoBox.getValue()));

            group.getChildren().add(new HBox(demoBox, selection));

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class EqualContent {
        private String name;
        EqualContent(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            return other != null;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

where selecting item B leads to the following:

[image]

Furthermore it seems impossible to actually select A afterwards.

A first option to solve this issue would obviosly be to modify the equal-method, but I don't want to do this in my case because my real class also has a compareTo and I want them to be consitent.

The second option would be to build a wrapper class around EqualContent that also considers the String representation for equals. I could certainly do that, but am not quite happy with it.

Am I missing an easier or more elegant solution?

Comment: Your problem is your overridden equal method. You are basically saying any Object that is not null is equal to all other Objects that are not null. I am guessing that means the value of the `ComboBox` never changes. If you delete that Overridden equals method, your problem will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My actual equals-method is more complex, but still leads to the situation demonstrated that two objects with different text are equal. The version with other!=null just seems to be the simplest example that fulfills the general contract of equals while showing the problem I have. Changig my actual method is something I would like to avoid, see the first option I mentioned. If you are interested, I could also provide some more context.

Comment: nearly all change notification in fx is based on equality (vs. identity) - the expressionHelper that does the notification for any property (f.i. the selectedItem or value of the combo) only fires if !oldValue.equals(newValue). No way around, afaik, except not basing your ui on identity ...

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Then it seems like ther is no way to get around building a wrapper class (short of changing equals, anyway). I'll edit in my generic wrapper class to provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: you might consider posting your solution as an answer and accept it - doing so will make it easier for others to find (as solution :)

Comment: just a comment: I would never use the toString in any way (other than debugging/logging). Instead, model that distinctive criterion for the wrapper and use a StringConverter for the ui.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. I moved my solution into an answer and can accept it tomorrow. As to the use of toString(): not being a "real" programmer, I'm probably guilty of quite a few more bad practises. I'll add it to the list of things I'll change when this work-in-progress approaches a state I'm otherwise happy with. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems I cannot get around using a wrapper. My sample solution is the following generic class (that provides more functionality as needed, but I had something like it already in another place):

```
static class RenameWrapper<T> {
        public final T wrappedObject;
        public final Callback<T, String> renamer;
        RenameWrapper(T wrappedObject, Callback<T, String> renamer) {
            this.wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
            this.renamer = renamer;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return renamer.call(wrappedObject);
        }
        public static <S> ArrayList<RenameWrapper<S>> wrapList(List<S> objectsToWrap, Callback<S, String> renamer) {
            ArrayList<RenameWrapper<S>> result = new ArrayList<RenameWrapper<S>>();
            objectsToWrap.forEach(o -> result.add(new RenameWrapper<S>(o, renamer)));
            return result;
        }
        /**
         * This and other are considered equal if other is a RenameWrapper that contains the same
         * wrappedObject according to their equals and the renamer produces the same String representation.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if(this == other) return true;
            if(!(other instanceof RenameWrapper)) return false;
            RenameWrapper<?> otherWrapper = (RenameWrapper<?>) other;
            return wrappedObject.equals(otherWrapper.wrappedObject) &&
                    this.toString().equals(other.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(wrappedObject, this.toString());
        }
    }
```

Then you can do

```
ObservableList<RenameWrapper<EqualContent>> wrappedContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    RenameWrapper.wrapList(content, eq -> eq.toString()));
```

and fill the ComboBox from wrappedContent instead of content as it was before.

Note that using toString() here is not exactly good practise...